# Weird behavior with non-webkit browsers menu animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

i have an issue concerning jQuery's animation with non-webkit browsers.
I've put a simplyfied version of it here http://jsfiddle.net/AdrianoRizzo/t3XUd/ 
the menu is an horizontal one, when you hover it the li should expand vertically but some weirdness appears there...

There is some extra markup like `<span>s` that is useful to me for other purposes, i need to keep them.

I don't use the `.stop()` method for controlling animation but rather `filter(':not(:animated)')` which i would like to keep.

I've done some searching but couldn't find anything, thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `float:left;` instead of  `display:inline-block;` this should solve your problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/t3XUd/3/